# Hyphenated compound surnames in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{GRW_high1,
        author = {Galatius, S{\o}ren and Randal-Williams, Oscar},
        title = {Homological stability for moduli spaces of high dimensional manifolds. {I}},
        journal = {Journal of the American Mathematical Society},
        volume = {31},
        year = {2018}
    }
\end{filecontents*}


% \usepackage[%
%   backend=biber,
%   style=alphabetic,
%   ]%
% {biblatex}
% \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{GRW_high1}

    \bibliographystyle{alpha} % <- comment out
    \bibliography{test}{}     % <- comment out
    % \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This generates the (intended) label `[GRW18]`.
However, if one comments out the BibTeX specific part and comments in the BibLaTeX configuration the generated label is `[GR18]`.

> How can the BibTeX behaviour be recreated with BibLaTeX?

I was only able to get `[GRW18]` by using `\namepart[compound=true]{family}` in `\DeclareLabelalphaNameTemplate`, removing the hyphen  – but I would like `[GRW18]` to be the standard behaviour.

Obviously adding `label={GRW}` to the bib entry achieves the desired result, but where is the fun in that …

Comment: Can you please show an MWE where you get "GRW" by colliding `.bib` entries? That should not be happening and I would consider this a bug. To me it seems that `compound` only takes into account names separated with a space and not hyphenated names. If you want to be able to take into account other separators for compound names as well, I suppose you would have to ask for it at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues

Comment: According to the manual hyphens should be regarded(?): "For static (non-varwidth) disambiguation in \DeclareLabelalphaTemplate, nameparts separated by whitespace or *hyphens* (compound names) as separate names for label generation." – But you are right, that only worked when the hyphen was removed in a copy of the above bib entry (the copied one becoming GRW).

Comment: You don't even need a colliding entry if you replace the hyphen with a space, as soon as you write `Randal Williams, Oscar`, `compound=true` works as expected. Since the manual says that hyphens should work as well, you should report this as a bug at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues

Comment: Done, see https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/272 – Thx for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `compound=true` for `\namepart` in `\DeclareLabelalphaNameTemplate` can help here (as alluded to in the question).

```
\DeclareLabelalphaNameTemplate{
  \namepart[use=true, pre=true, strwidth=1, compound=true]{prefix}
  \namepart[compound=true]{family}
}
```

There was a bug in Biber versions prior to 2.13 that mean that hyphen characters were nor considered for compound names. The issue was resolved after it was reported in https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/272.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelalphaNameTemplate{
  \namepart[use=true, pre=true, strwidth=1, compound=true]{prefix}
  \namepart[compound=true]{family}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{GRW_high1,
  author  = {Galatius, Søren and Randal-Williams, Oscar},
  title   = {Homological stability for moduli spaces of high dimensional manifolds. {I}},
  journal = {Journal of the American Mathematical Society},
  volume  = {31},
  year    = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{GRW_high1}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [GRW18]]